# Unclickable Links + Navbar in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, twitter-bootstrap, hyperlink

I have a fixed navbar on top and some links (Privacy, Sitemap etc) in the footer. when clicking on them nothing happens. Hovering and dropdown works, but the clicked link is not seen. It works in Firefox (19), but not in Chrome.

Could someone help? I use the standard bootstrap-css.

```
  <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="containerr" align="center">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>    
        </button>


      <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="2">
       <tr>
        ...
       </tr>
      </table>  

      <div class="nav-collapse">

        <ul class="nav">

          <li class="active"><a href="1.html" class="activator">1</a></li>
          <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
          <li><a href="2.html" class="activator">2</a></li>
          <li class="divider-vertical"></li>

          <li class="dropdown" id="iddropdown">

            <a href="3.html" class="dropdown-toggle activator" data-hover="dropdown" id="iddropdowninner">
            3 </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a class="activator" href="3.html#collapseOne">3.1</a></li>                
              <li><a class="activator" href="3.html#collapseTwo">3.2</a></li>               
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
          <li><a href="4.html" class="activator">4</a></li>            
        </ul>        

       </div><!-- /.nav-collapse -->
      </div><!-- /.container -->
     </div><!-- /.navbar-inner -->
    </div><!-- /.navbar -->
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Q2gj7/

Many thanks!

Comment: The links in your code work fine for me. http://jsfiddle.net/Q2gj7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In chrome version 32.0.1700.102 if you are using the css
`text-indent:-somebignumber;` to hide the text it breaks the links

INSTEAD don't use text-indent at all but do use `color:Transparent;`
I also had `overflow:hidden;`